# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar el error "Usted intentó cargar un archivo con un tipo de compresión desconocido (application/zip) (...)" en PHPMyAdmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

Recién he instalado xampp en mi computadora y he intentado importar un archivo excel en formato OpenDocument (ODS) para una base de datos, pero a la hora de cargarlo me aparece el siguiente mensaje:

> "Usted intentó cargar un archivo con un tipo de compresión desconocido (application/zip). Este tipo de compresión puede no estar implementado o quizá no ha sido habilitado en su archivo de configuración."

Al principio pensé que era el archivo pero traté de importarlo en otras computadoras con xampp y no hubo inconveniente, entonces ¿cuál creen que sea el problema? Ya intenté desde hacer un archivo nuevo hasta comprimirlo en un formato diferente, pero nada.

Comment: No queda claro si es exportar o importar, empezas diciendo una cosa, pero por contexto se entiende otra. Entiendo que es importar y en tal caso deberías asegurarte de tener las extensiones habilitadas en PHP. Revisa tu `php.ini`

Comment: Y porque no haces un **.sql**?

Comment: Perdón, pequeño error de gramática, es una importación. 
¿Las extensiones del del documento php.ini? ¿Sobre que línea específicamente?

Answer (score 1):

lo he solucionado con quitar el ";" de la linea ";extension=zip" del archivo php.ini, ahora si me deja cargar los archivos *.ODS
no sé si tendrá algo que ver que use XAMPP control center en lugar de WAMPSERVER??

Comment: Tiene que ver con que, en cada caso, hay que configurar el PHP del servidor que se use y no todos vienen configurados igual ;)